# sending parameters between joomla article

Tags: php, joomla

How can I send parameters like

```
radios=oneway&asal=CGK&tujuan=DPS&pergi=2013-12-31&pulang=&dewasa=1&anak=0&bayi=0
```

into an joomla article which injected by my custom php script with "sourcerer"?

In my case, I want to create an custom php article like search engine for example, and pass its parameter to other joomla article which customed by my custom php. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are trying to pass parameters in url,

You already mentioned your first article is Custom PHP it send to another article that is also custom PHP.

So just use First custom PHP have some forms and second have some variables that recieves from first one.

you can simply access any article like below,

something like

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=69&catid=14&Itemid=471
```

set this as form action with second `article Id` and `catId` the submitting first one send data to the second article.

If you have any doubt in [Include HTML or PHP codes into Joomla article](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-include-html-or-php-codes-into-joomla-article) ,

Hope this makes clear.

Comment: If I have some custom php in article (ex. id=1) and in sender form action I write [code]www.ex.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1[code]. is that what did you mean?

Comment: in your first article form action set to second article link and your extra params as form fields, your second article is also custom so you can retrieve that variable there, hope its clear

Comment: So, in action code of first article is like this "www.ex.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1". is that true? (example of second article which has id=1)